# updating records using php and android

Tags: php, android

How can i update records using android and php. when  i update record in android, didnt update any record on specific email, im guessing that my code on php has the problem.

here is my code on android

```
 public void changeprofile(){


    HashMap postData = new HashMap();

    String emailch = emailchange.getText().toString();

    String password = passch.getText().toString();
    String firstname = fnamech.getText().toString();
    String lastname = lnamech.getText().toString();
    String contact = contactch.getText().toString();
    String confirm = conpassch.getText().toString();

   postData.put("emailc", emailch);
    postData.put("fname", firstname);
    postData.put("lname", lastname);
    postData.put("Password", password);
    postData.put("Confirm", confirm);
    postData.put("contact", contact);


    PostResponseAsyncTask task79 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(ChangeProfile.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String s) {
            Log.d(LOG, s);
            if (s.contains("change")) {
                Toast.makeText(ChangeProfile.this, "Successfully Change Profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent in = new Intent(ChangeProfile.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }  else if (s.contains("match"))    {
                Toast.makeText(ChangeProfile.this, "The password didnt match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } else if (s.contains("Fillup"))    {
                Toast.makeText(ChangeProfile.this, "Fill up the form", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ChangeProfile.this, "Invalid Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
    task79.execute("http://10.0.2.2/wawi/change.php");


}
```

and here is the code on php (change.php)

```
require_once('connection.php');


    if(isset($_POST['fname'])){


    $email = $_POST['emailc'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $confirm = $_POST['Confirm'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];

 if( $password == '' || $confirm == '' || $fname == '' || $lname == '' || $contact== ''){
 echo 'Fillup';
 }else{


if($confirm == $password)
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='$password', fname='$fname', lname='$lname', contact='$contact' WHERE email='$email'");

    echo "change";
}else
{
    echo "match";

}
```

Comment: The usual question, no sense in doing anything prior to answering that: what does your http servers error log file show?

Comment: Apache error log [Sun Feb 12 17:40:09.302451 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4748:tid 264] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads

Comment: You forgot the php opening tag at the beginning of the script: `<?php`

Comment: And you have a definite syntax error in your script: the first `if` condition openes a block that is never closed.

Comment: Apart from that: your code relies on the old, outdated and long deprecated `mysql...()` extension. Along with the fact that you do no escaping whatsoever that makes your code highly vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Anyone can take over your system.